# Syntax problem in Bootstrap Vue table with scoped slot in PUG template

Tags: vue.js, pug, bootstrap-vue

From the Bootstrap Vue table documentation it is possible to render data customized.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#scoped-field-slots

The example shows the following template:

```
<template v-slot:cell(index)="data">
  {{ data.index + 1 }}
</template>
```

I'm using PUG as a template language and I'm having some trouble with its syntax. I didn't find the correct way to "translate" the above example to PUG syntax.

This doesn't work because of the colon:

```
template(v-slot:cell(index)="data") {{ data.index + 1 }}
```

Also this does not seem to be correct:

```
template(v-slot(cell(index)="data")) {{ data.index + 1 }}
```

---

### Update #1

This is my field definition:

```
  fields: [
    "index",
    {
      key: "name",
      label: this.$t("document.name"),
      sortable: true
    }
  ]
```

And this is the template:

```
b-table#filesList(
  v-if="list.length > 0"
  :items="list"
  :fields="fields"
  stacked="md"
  striped
  responsive
)
  template(v-slot:cell(index)="data") {{ data.index + 1 }}
```

This only shows an empty "Index" column. If I change the template to the deprected `slot` and `slot-scope` synctax it's working:

```
template(slot="index" slot-scope="data") {{ data.index + 1 }}
```

Comment: Have you added a `index` field, to your fields array?

Comment: @hiws Yes, the `index` field has been added.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap-Vue version `2.0.0-rc.x`? It has a different syntax than the current version for table slots. `v-slot` also requires vue `v2.6.x`, so make sure you have that installed.

Comment: We're using `"bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.20","vue": "^2.6.6"`

Comment: That's the issue then. The `cell(fieldKey)` slot naming was introduced in stable release `v2.0.0`, so that it was compatible with the new `v-slot` syntax that was introduced at the time. So you'll have to use the old slot naming which was just the field key like so `v-slot:index="data"`, or update to version `v2.x.x`. If you can't update, i would suggest you clone the [git repo](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/tree/v2.0.0-rc.20) for your version and generate the documentation locally, to avoid confusion, since a lot has changed since your verison.

Comment: You're right. Thanks! I locally upgraded to the Bootstrap Vue 2.14.0 and now it's just working :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the pug "translation" of the code example in the link you provided.

I haven't used pug before, but the code below looks like it's working in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/jObKpJX).

Since you need virtual fields, you need to provide a `fields` array to the `fields` prop on `b-table`. That includes all the fields you want to show.

```
b-table(small, :fields="fields", :items="items", responsive="sm")
  template(v-slot:cell(index)="data") {{ data.index + 1 }}

  template(v-slot:cell(name)="data")
    b.text-info {{ data.value.last.toUpperCase() }},
    b {{ data.value.first }}

  template(v-slot:cell(nameage)="data") {{ data.item.name.first }} is {{ data.item.age }} years old

  template(v-slot:cell()="data") 
    i {{ data.value }}
```

### Update

The above syntax requires Bootstrap version `2.0.0` and up.

The table slot naming for `2.0.0-rc.28` (and ONLY this version). was [field], HEAD[field] and FOOT[field].

In version 2.0.0-rc.27 and below it's field, HEAD_field, FOOT_field.

If you're using a version below that, i would suggest you update if you can, to get the latest features and fixes. But if you can't, you can instead clone the [github repo](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue) and generate the documentation for the version you're using. This will allow you to see what is available at the time, and avoid future confusion.

Comment: As mentioned in an above comment, I upgraded `bootstrap-vue` to the current stable version 2.14.0. This resolves the problem.